# How can i modify my code so it will be safe from deadlock?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, deadlock

I am trying to understand how deadlocks works. I know that deadlock is when 2 or more threads are blocked forever, and they are waiting for each other to exit from the block state, but it never happens. 
I have the following code and i want to modify it to make it safe from deadlock. Can someone tell me how to do it and explain it to me to understand it?

```
public class CList extends Thread {
private int item;
private Clist next;
private int updateCount=0;
public synchronized void replace(int old, int neww, Clist startedAt) {
if(item==old) {
item=neww;
updateCount++;
}
if(next!=startedAt)
next.replace(old, neww, startedAt);
}
public void run() {
 for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
 replace(i, i-1, this);
 }

public Clist(int item, Clist next) {
this.item=item;
this.next=next;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
 Clist clist3 = new Clist(60, null);
 Clist clist2 = new Clist(40, clist3);
 Clist clist1 = new Clist(20, clist2);
 clist3.next = clist1;
 clist1.start();
 clist2.start();
 clist3.start();
}
}
```

Comment: "I want to modify it to make it safe from deadlock" - From **which** deadlock do you want to be protected?

Comment: @Tsyvarev well if you can show me an example it would be appreciated

Comment: You want us to find a deadlock in the code which you have provided without any comment or description? I may *guess* that deadlock could occure in the inner call to `next.replace()` in the synchronized `replace()` function. This probably is possible, because you have looped the Client's list with `clist3.next = clist1;`. I am not sure why are you doing that. You may remove given line for fix the deadlocks.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the intended logic.

For a consistent update on a single object, there is no need to hold a lock for a different object, so the deadlock can be prevented by not holding the lock when invoking `next.replace(…)`:

```
public void replace(int old, int neww, Clist startedAt) {
    synchronized(this) {
        if(item==old) {
            item=neww;
            updateCount++;
        }
    }
    if(next!=startedAt)
        next.replace(old, neww, startedAt);
}
```

On a higher level, the application may require holding the lock of a different object, to ensure that the updates to multiple objects happen in a certain way. E.g. in your example code where three threads do entirely redundant work, the actual purpose seems to be, to produce a deadlock, so there is no way to eliminate the deadlock and retain the original purpose.